# Flickr: add tag to other people's photos in batch

Tags: batch, flickr, tagging

Let's say I perform a search on Flickr, and I want to add the same tag to all the search results. Adding this tag is allowed when opening the search results one-by-one, but I cannot find any way of doing it in a batch, as if they were my pics. Is there a clean way out, without handling the API?